# Is it necessary to have an attorney-client relationship for a lawyer to give legal advice to someone?

Tags: united-states, lawyer, oregon, attorney-client-relationship

If a lawyer gives legal advice to someone who is not his/her client, is that legal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, a person becomes a client of a lawyer by virtue of the lawyer giving advice to them. It is quite easy for a lawyer to accidentally create a lawyer-client relationship. But, a lawyer can give legal advice to someone who is not his/her client subject primarily to the limitation of Rule of Professional Conduct 4.3 which states:

> In dealing on behalf of a client with a person who is not represented
> by counsel, a lawyer shall not state or imply that the lawyer is
> disinterested. When the lawyer knows or reasonably should know that
> the unrepresented person misunderstands the lawyer’s role in the
> matter, the lawyer shall make reasonable efforts to correct the
> misunderstanding. **The lawyer shall not give legal advice to an
> unrepresented person, other than the advice to secure counsel, *if the
> lawyer knows or reasonably should know that the interests of such a
> person are or have a reasonable possibility of being in conflict with
> the interests of the client*.**

So, basically, if a lawyer gives legal advice to someone who isn't his client, the lawyer needs to be clear that both the person is not someone with a conflict of interest with his/her client, and that the lawyer provides the disclaimer that the lawyer does not have the third-party's interests at heart when giving the advice.

If the non-client is adverse to the lawyer's client, or otherwise is in a conflict of interest with the lawyer's client, the lawyer may not give that person legal advice other than to retain a lawyer of their own.

A lawyer giving legal advice to a non-client is also subject to Rule of Professional Conduct 4.1 which requires the lawyer to be truthful in communications with third-parties. This rule states:

> In the course of representing a client a lawyer shall not knowingly:
>
> (a) make a false statement of material fact **or law** to a third person;
> or
>
> (b) fail to disclose a material fact to a third person when disclosure
> is necessary to avoid assisting a criminal or fraudulent act by a
> client, unless disclosure is prohibited by Rule 1.6.

Note also that "legal advice" means applications of the law to a particular person's actual factual situation, for use by that person, and not merely provision of general educational information about the law.